# Lodash And OR logic in filters

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to implement this logic in my lodash `_.filter`

```
if (bolMine && !bolUnassigned)
{
    o => o.AssignedDriver == CurrentLoggedOnUser;
}
else if (bolMine && bolUnassigned)
{
     o => (o.AssignedDriver == CurrentLoggedOnUser || o.AssignedDriver == 0);
}
else if (!bolMine && bolUnassigned)
{
     o => o.AssignedDriver == CurrentLoggedOnUser;
}


if (bolExvat)
{
    o => o.ExVatOrder == bolExtVat;
}

if(intCategory > 0)

{

    o => o.OrderCategory == intCategory

}
```

How do I convert this to my iteratee?

```
 this.filteredOrders = _.filter(this.orders, iteratee);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pass `o` to `_.filter` (or rather, the arrow functions you're creating but never assigning to anything)? Or how to write your chunk of code into a function which you pass to `_.filter`? Sorry, I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: Where are all of the other variables coming from? (`bolMine`, `bolUnassigned`, etc)?

Comment: @kqcef That is pseudocode (algorithm) which I want to implement it in Lodash.

Comment: @MikeC: You are absolutely write - how to write my chunk of code in _.filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function filterOrders(o) {
    if (bolMine && !bolUnassigned)
    {
        return o.AssignedDriver == CurrentLoggedOnUser;
    }
    else if (bolMine && bolUnassigned)
    {
        return (o.AssignedDriver == CurrentLoggedOnUser || o.AssignedDriver == 0);
    }
    else if (!bolMine && bolUnassigned)
    {
        return o.AssignedDriver == CurrentLoggedOnUser;
    }


    if (bolExvat)
    {
        return o.ExVatOrder == bolExtVat;
    }

    if(intCategory > 0)
    {
        return o.OrderCategory == intCategory
    }
}

this.filteredOrders = _.filter(this.orders, filterOrders);
```

Comment: Whilst this is not exactly what I needed but your idea solved the issue for me on how to pass the filterOrders. Thank you!